# how to make website responsive vertically?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage and I have the "body" wrapped around all my content. But when I do this webpage responsive and want the body to enlarge the web content the body stops enlarge the content vertically. It do enlarge the content when I increase the width but not vertically. I don't want the extra black area.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  padding-bottom: 10vh;
  padding-top: 10vh;
  padding-right: 10vh;
  padding-left: 10vh;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper {
  position: static;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  align-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

#wrapper2 {
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.cell1 {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  text-align: center;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.cell2 {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  text-align: center;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.cell3 {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  text-align: center;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.dogname {
  color: white;
  top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.dogtext {
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  #wrapper2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .cell1 {
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .cell2 {
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .cell3 {
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .dogname {
    display: none;
  }
  .dogtext {
    display: block;
  }
  body {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

    <div class="cell1">
      <p class="dogname">David Neal</p>
      <img src="images/image1.jpg" />
    </div>

    <p class="dogtext">After the hunt (1870) by David Neal</p>

    <div class="cell2">
      <p class="dogname">BG Tiepolo</p>
      <img src="images/image2.jpg" />
    </div>

    <p class="dogtext">Portrait of a Toy Spaniel Belonging to the Infanta Maria Josefa of Bourbon (1763) by Giovanni Battista Tiepolo</p>

    <div class="cell3">
      <p class="dogname">AF Desportes</p>
      <img src="images/image3.jpg" />

      <p class="dogtext">Chienne blanche devant un buisson de sureau (1714) by Alexandre-François Desportes</p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper2">

    <div class="cell1">
      <p class="dogname">JC Merck</p>
      <img src="images/image4.jpg" />

      <p class="dogtext">Ulmer Dogge (1705) by Johann Christof Merck</p>

    </div>

    <div class="cell2">
      <p class="dogname">John Wootton</p>
      <img src="images/image5.jpg" />

      <p class="dogtext">A Grey Spotted Hound (1738) by John Wootton</p>
    </div>

    <div class="cell3">
      <p class="dogname">EH Landseer</p>
      <img src="images/image6.jpg" />

      <p class="dogtext">A Distinguished Member of the Humane Society (1838) by Edwin Henry Landseer</p>


    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what do you want to achieve, but generally, you can use media queries for height and combine them with the ones for width.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) , screen and (max-height: 600px) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, your webpage is vertically scaled based on the height of the content. To always have it at least be one viewheight high, you can insert this rule into your css:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```